# How do I create this case statements in proc sql and append when tables are overwritten?

Tags: sql, macros, sas, proc-sql

I have spent several months data mining and creating a technique to find out information for a company. I am having trouble with the putting the data into an appropriate and valuable presentation on how to summarize information in SAS. I have 3 questions.

1)how do I say in proc sql " If matched_by_t2 > b2_c2 then add in new column "no bueno"

2)is there a way to have "(BC_C2/ original_count) %" How would i insert that percent sign

3) also if I run this query multiple times for a list of datasets how do I get those new tables that are named the same "e_data_unmatched" 
append each time a new table is created and overwritten In imgur I show two rows each timie the program runs the tables get overwritten so I want to ensure that each time the loop runs the new records append to the table rather than overwrite. 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkuyj.jpg) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkuyj.jpg

Thank you!

```
    proc sql;
create table wanted as
select t1.occurences as original_count
      ,t2.occurences as matched_by_T1
      ,t3.occurences as matched_by_T2
      ,t2.occurences+t3.occurences as B2_C2
      ,t4.occurences as not_matched
      ,t5.occurences as matched_by_t2
from (select count(*) as occurences from query_for_reports1) t1
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from query_for_reports1 where edsys is not null) t2
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from e_data_unmatched where ip is not null) t3
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from WORK.E_DAT_UNMATCHED where IpS= .) t4
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from work.Append_table13) t5
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Add new column "no bueno" in sql set value based on conditiong " If matched_by_t2 > b2_c2" 
2) concatenate percentage sign
 proc sql;
create table wanted as
select t1.occurences as original_count
      ,t2.occurences as matched_by_T1
      ,t3.occurences as matched_by_T2
      ,t2.occurences+t3.occurences as B2_C2
      ,t4.occurences as not_matched
      ,t5.occurences as matched_by_t2,
case when t3.occurences> t5.occurences then 0 
else 1 end as no_bueno,
 CAST(((t2.occurences+t3.occurences)/ t1.occurences) as nvarchar(5)) +'%'
from (select count(*) as occurences from query_for_reports1) t1
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from query_for_reports1 where edsys is not null) t2
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from e_data_unmatched where ip is not null) t3
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from WORK.E_DAT_UNMATCHED where IpS= .) t4
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from work.Append_table13) t5
;
quit;
```

Comment: Multiple things are wrong here. For one, your `cast` line is not valid SAS syntax (not in this proc sql at least). Second, it seems she wants to conditionnaly have the value "no bueno" in a column, not a column called "no bueno". Lastly, you added some stuff to her code without correcting her mistakes (e.g. duplicate `matched_by_t2` columns in select statement); which means that, even if your additions were correct, this code would still not work.

Comment: @user2877959 is there a way to say his answer was right for 50% of my question? What is stack etiquette?

Comment: I would say that this answer was right for 33% of your question assuming he was correct in his understanding of your first point. I guess that stack philosophy is that you upvote an answer that was useful and/or mark as accepted an answer that completely answered your question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

To build on your query and try to answer all three questions:

1) If you want a new column containing the value "no bueno" when the condition is true, you add the following column to your select clause:

```
case 
  when matched_by_t2>t2.occurences+t3.occurences then "no bueno"
end as new_column_1
```

If however what you want is a flag-type value in a column called no bueno, you can use @Trushna's suggestion

2) There are two ways to do this. You can either store the value as a character variable with the percent sign hardcoded in it :

```
catx(' ',(t2.occurences+t3.occurences)/t1.occurences,'%') as new_column_2
```

or you can store the value as a numeric variable and *display* it with a percent sign using a format:

```
(t2.occurences+t3.occurences)/t1.occurences as new_column_2 format=percent.
```

3) one way to use this query to add its output to a table each time is to use an `insert into` query instead of a `create table`:

```
proc sql;
insert into wanted
select [...]
;
quit;
```

Bare in mind that the table needs to exist for an `insert into` to be successful. In your case, you would have to use the `create table` syntax the first time and then the `insert into syntax` every subsequent time.

I have to point out that, although I am not aware of your workflow nor the context in which you are doing this, the way you are trying to achieve this seems very sub-optimal and you might want to consider rethinking your process.